# How do I run games from my onboard graphics even though I have a discrete graphics card connected?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, graphics, integrated-graphics

I have an i5 2500K with Intel HD3000 onboard graphics, and I have a (really bad) ATI Radeon HD2400 card also plugged in, purely to run an extra monitor from.

How can I ensure that when I play a game, it uses the Intel HD3000 and not the HD2400 to process it? The HD3000 is quite a bit better, but I fear that it assumes that any discrete card is the one that I want to be using, so I'm getting poor performance in games.

Thanks

(the monitor on which the game is is run from the onboard graphics)

Comment: Which operating system?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Ati radeon 2400 but i had pro version. It sucks for gaming, but the **HD3000 is way better**. *Unplug your graphics card* and try booting your system. It should work. You might need to install some Intel drivers that you got from cd or download newer ones from their web site.